# C# application working only in workspace folders

Tags: c#, forms, email, smtp, winapp

I've configured a C# Windows Application form in my project for sending emails, the project is in my Work Folders which is assigned to a local server.

The form works fine when I execute (or debug) the project on Work Folders and sends emails perfectly, but when I change the location of project folder to another location - like desktop/program files folder, the form hangs for a while after which the message "operation has timed out" appears.

Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Comment: sounds like a firewall or port closed... Do you use port 25 or something like that?

Comment: i use gmail account with smpt.gmail.com and 587 port, i unbound the port but it does not work  ....

Comment: try to telnet from the computer with the issue to port 587 and check if it is OPEN

Comment: try something like `telnet smpt.gmail.com 587`

Comment: i tried it, this is the respose Connecting To smpt.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 587: Connect faile ..... any way to solve pls

Comment: i tried again its ok "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e2sm27854478wrr.85 - gsmtp"